# iOS push notification in foreground - detect when notification's banner was ignored by user

Tags: ios, push-notification

When app is running in foreground, how can I identify if the user ignored notification's banner?

I did implement delegate's method `userNotificationCenter: willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:` and the notification's banner is beeing presented normally:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter: (UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification: (UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler: (nonnull void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

When banner get tapped, I can handle an action through method `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:`.

My problem is that *I need to trigger an action when user ignores the banner*.

How can I handle it?

Comment: Start a timer when the banner is shown and cancel it when they tap on the banner. If the timer fires then they didn't tap the banner

Comment: @Paulw11 interesting answer, I'll try it. Thank you!